# KF5 Init package in Kubuntu

Tags: software-installation, kde, cmake

I'm trying to install `Konsole` from source but after running 'CMake' I got the following error :

```
Could NOT find KF5Init (missing: KF5Init_DIR)
Could NOT find KF5Init: found neither KF5InitConfig.cmake nor kf5init-config.cmake
```

But there is no such package to install : `libkf5init-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmake files are provided by the package `kinit-dev` :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Init/KF5InitConfig.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Init/KF5InitConfigVersion.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Init/KF5InitMacros.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Init/kde5init_dummy.cpp.in
```

`$ sudo apt install kinit-dev`